# How to return back to app from inAppBrowser in ionic 3

Tags: javascript, ionic3

I'm working with PayTM web based payment gateway in ionic app. I used inAppBrowser to open that gateway and now I want to return back from the webpage to my app. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Provide some code that you tried. Also, check the "on" method for inappbrowser, on exit event, get the last loaded URL and perform the required action

Comment: Thanks a ton @ASH_HBK for giving me a little idea about how do i go with the approach. I used browser.on('loadstart').subcribe({...}); to get the current url and compared that.. if it was true then i closed the browser. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code.

```
browser.on('loadstart').subscribe((e) => {
     let compareURL = "https://myurl.com/folder_name/filename.php?CODE=XXXXX";
     console.log(e.url);
     if(e.url === compareURL){
       this.navCtrl.setRoot(ConfirmationPage, {
       orderId: this.orderId
     })
       browser.close();
       console.log('browser closed');
    }

    }, err => {
          console.error(err);
    });
```